# Flutter ListView on click navigate to another screen

Tags: android, listview, flutter, dart

I'm learning Flutter. I have a ListView and I would like to make the list items clickable. My idea is that when the user clicks on an item, it will be directed to another screen. Each buttom should leads to different screen. I'm having trouble implementing it, I don't know what to use: gesture detector or ontap. What should I do? Should I use ListTile instead of ListView?

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = "ListView List";

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: new ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            children: List.generate(choices.length, (index) {
                return Center(
                  child: ChoiceCard(choice: choices[index], item: choices[index]),
                );
            }
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }
}

class Choice {
  const Choice({this.title, this.icon});

  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
}

const List<Choice> choices = const <Choice>[
  const Choice(title: 'This is a Car', icon: Icons.directions_car),
  const Choice(title: 'This is a Bicycle', icon: Icons.directions_bike),
  const Choice(title: 'This is a Boat', icon: Icons.directions_boat),
  const Choice(title: 'This is a Bus', icon: Icons.directions_bus),
  const Choice(title: 'This is a Train', icon: Icons.directions_railway),
];

class ChoiceCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChoiceCard(
      {Key key, this.choice, this.onTap, @required this.item, this.selected: false}
    ) : super(key: key);

  final Choice choice;
  final VoidCallback onTap;
  final Choice item;
  final bool selected;



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextStyle textStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1;
    if (selected)
      textStyle = textStyle.copyWith(color: Colors.lightGreenAccent[400]);
        return Card(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Container( 
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  child: Icon(choice.icon, size:80.0, color: textStyle.color,)),
                new Expanded( 
                  child: new Container( 
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  child:                    
                    Text(choice.title, style: null, textAlign: TextAlign.left, maxLines: 5,),
                  )
                ),
            ],
           crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below

Step 1: To allow `Navigator.push` work, you can move `MaterialApp` to upper level 
Step 2: In `onTap` pass `Navigator.push`

```
ChoiceCard(
                  choice: choices[index],
                  item: choices[index],
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => Detail(choice: choices[index])),
                    );
                  },
                ),
```

Step 3: Wrap `Card` with `InkWell` and call `onTap()`

```
 return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        onTap();
      },
      child: Card(
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: HomePage());
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final title = "ListView List";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: new ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            children: List.generate(choices.length, (index) {
              return Center(
                child: ChoiceCard(
                  choice: choices[index],
                  item: choices[index],
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => Detail(choice: choices[index])),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              );
            })));
  }
}

class Choice {
  const Choice({this.title, this.icon});

  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
}

const List<Choice> choices = const <Choice>[
  const Choice(title: 'This is a Car', icon: Icons.directions_car),
  const Choice(title: 'This is a Bicycle', icon: Icons.directions_bike),
  const Choice(title: 'This is a Boat', icon: Icons.directions_boat),
  const Choice(title: 'This is a Bus', icon: Icons.directions_bus),
  const Choice(title: 'This is a Train', icon: Icons.directions_railway),
];

class ChoiceCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChoiceCard(
      {Key key,
      this.choice,
      this.onTap,
      @required this.item,
      this.selected: false})
      : super(key: key);

  final Choice choice;
  final VoidCallback onTap;
  final Choice item;
  final bool selected;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextStyle textStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1;
    if (selected)
      textStyle = textStyle.copyWith(color: Colors.lightGreenAccent[400]);
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        onTap();
      },
      child: Card(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  child: Icon(
                    choice.icon,
                    size: 80.0,
                    color: textStyle.color,
                  )),
              new Expanded(
                  child: new Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: Text(
                  choice.title,
                  style: null,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  maxLines: 5,
                ),
              )),
            ],
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          )),
    );
  }
}

class Detail extends StatelessWidget {
  final Choice choice;
  Detail({this.choice});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Route"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("${choice.title}"),
          Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: Text('Go back!'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!

Comment: How would you do it if for every icon you need a different color?

Answer (score -1):

```
import 'package:easy_buss/screen/client.dart';    
import 'package:easy_buss/screen/invoice.dart';    
import 'package:easy_buss/screen/invoice_settings.dart';    
import 'package:easy_buss/screen/payment_info.dart';    
import 'package:easy_buss/widgets/payment_info_form.dart';   
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';    

class Settings extends StatefulWidget {    
  @override    
  _SettingsState createState() => _SettingsState();    
}

class _SettingsState extends State<Settings> {    
  List<IconData> _icon = [    
    Icons.accessible,    
    Icons.analytics,
    Icons.question_answer_sharp,
    Icons.message,
    Icons.share,
    Icons.star_half,
    Icons.add_business,
    Icons.privacy_tip,
  ];

 List<String> _title = [
   'Invoice Settings',
    'Reports',
    'Frequently Ask Questions',
    'Write Us',
    'Share With A Friends',
    'Rate Us',
    'Terms & Conditions',
    'Privacy Policy',
  ];

  List<Color> _colors = [
    Colors.cyan,
    Colors.yellow,
    Colors.red,
    Colors.purple,
    Colors.orange,
    Colors.grey,
    Colors.pink[300],
    Colors.green[200],
  ];

  List _items = [
   InvoiceSettings(),
   InvoiceSettings(),
   InvoiceSettings(),
   InvoiceSettings(),
   InvoiceSettings(),
   InvoiceSettings(),
   InvoiceSettings(),
   InvoiceSettings(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return ListView.separated(
     itemCount: _title.length,
     separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          left: 10,
          right: 10,
        ),
        child: Divider(
          thickness: 1,
        ),
      ),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => ListTile(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => _items[index],
            ),
          );
        },
        leading: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            color: _colors[index],
          ),
          child: Icon(
           _icon[index],
            color: Colors.white,
            size: 20,
          ),
        ),
        title: Text(
          _title[index],
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
         ),
        ),
        trailing: Icon(
          Icons.chevron_right,
          size: 40,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please write the relevant description with your code. Code only answers are not recommended. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer